# Programmatically Control Computer in Python

Tags: python, ui-automation

I searched a lot, but couldn't find any precise answer to my question. I would like to programmatically be able to simulate user interactions with the computer. I would like to target OSX since that's what I am working on. For example, I would launch Dashboard or Mission Control, move the mouse and click on things, open a keyboard, etc.

I wonder if I should use Linux with Xlib or something like that... Would I be more free to execute these kinds of operations? And do you know any libraries that allow them easily, in Python preferably?

Comment: If you want to target OS X, applescript has a lot of convenient ways to automate the programs on it. It's not the *best* language... but it's decent for program automation on apple computers.

Comment: pywinauto is a package for python that lets you do this.  AutoIt is its own language that also does this and is free, ranorex is paid software that does this... as such I believe this post is a request for highly opinion based which tool is best, which is against SO rules :/

Comment: @JoranBeasley As OP doesn't know of any, I think this is not opinion based. We can't slavishly follow the rules past the point of common sense.

Comment: Yeah I gave your answer a +1, but really I think that now that he knows of some and some better search terms it is an OT question... but meh thats just my 2c

Answer (score 4):

This kind of software is called a "robot", or "ui automation", which makes googling a little difficult. Here is one in python: http://code.google.com/p/robotframework/

Comment: Thank for the answer! I am not sure is Robot is the path I'll take, but the keywords "ui automation" definitely helped me in my search. I'll take a deeper look at it!

Comment: @JustinD. You're welcome! There's a lot out there to choose from.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org) for this sort of thing. Last time I needed to automate a GUI app on OS X, I wrote a standalone Jython script which used Sikuli as a library.

You can also use the Sikuli IDE if you want to get something working quickly, which can be nice for experimentation.